# How to show analytically that $x^4-4x^3-2x^2+16x+24=0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials

I'm trying to study a function and I need to prove that $x^4-4x^3-2x^2+16x+24=0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{R}$ in a simple way.

I drew the polynomial function $f(x)=x^4-4x^3-2x^2+16x+24$ with Wolfram and saw that the graph doesn't intersect the $x$ axis but I'd like to know if there is any simple method to prove that without Wolfram or any other "external supports".

Comment: Depends on how one defines "simple." You can look at its discriminant to prove the function has no real roots. (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots))

Comment: The given polynomial can be written as Product of 2 polynomials with no real solutions...

Comment: @dmtri Can you write those two polynomials down? This is an irreducible quartic over the rationals. It factors as a product of two quadratics over the reals, of course, but proving that those have no real roots is equivalent to OP's problem.

Comment: I considered $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)= x^4-4x^3-2x^2+16x+24$, and it produced a system of $a,b, c, d$, but I think I made mistake because after checking with wolfalpha it has irrational solutions and difficult to find,  as you mentioned. So my way of thinking was wrong, sorry.@dxiv

Answer (score 22, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^4-4x^3-2x^2+16x+24=(x^2-2x-4)^2+2x^2+8>0.\tag{1}$$
**My motivation:** the terms $-4x^3$ and $16x$ are annoying since they can be either positive or negative, so I wanted to put them in a square. Then I tried $$(x^2-2x+b)^2=x^4-4x^3+(2b+4)x^2-4bx+b^2.$$
Now, taking $b=-4$ produces $(1)$. I was just lucky!

Comment: You should probably show where the square term comes from.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Done.